# How to detect if "Show end date" is checked?

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

Trying to find a way to get the value of the checkbox "Show end date" on a date field on drupal 7.

Is it stored somewhere in the database? Can't find it. 
Its definitely not in the $node object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's stored against the field settings in the `field_config` table. You can get access to it through the API with [`field_info_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7)

```
$field_info = field_info_field('field_name');
$to_date_setting = $field_info['settings']['todate']; // optional, required, etc
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer my question because this only returns the field set up on the site wide configuration and not the specific selection of the "Show end date" check box on the node.